# Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my flask application in vscode. I have setup a venv named dream_env and have activated it yet it doesn't let me set the environment variables. I have used:  `set FLASK_APP=dream_blog.py` and nothing happens. When I do `flask run` the error above pops up. Furthermore I have accessed the launch.json file and it also has "FLASK_APP": "./dream_blog.py", in the "env" category. How can I set the environment variable and start my flask app?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, if you are running powershell then setting environment variables is achieved differently. In the venv, just do:

```
$Env:FLASK_APP=".\file.py"
```